# Avoid inline equations starting on left the margin

Tags: math-mode, inline

I would like to avoid that ANY inline equation starts on left the margin.

The solution I have for that right now is to compile the document, check where this happened and add a `~` in front of the inline equation and then recompile. But this is quite annoying.

This

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada 
iada iada iada iada iada iada $2+2=4$ iada iada iada
\end{document}
```

would produce a break as

```
iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada 
2+2=4 iada iada iada
```

But I rather a similar effect as here (only without having to include the `~` everytime!)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada 
iada iada iada iada iada iada~$2+2=4$ iada iada iada
\end{document}
```

which would give

```
iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada  
iada 2+2=4 iada iada iada
```

Comment: What is the problem with equations touching the left margin?

Comment: Inline equations often break the flow of the text. Avoiding this can thus make the text easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that I agree with Marienplatz's comment, this is a simple attempt to achieve what you want, but you have to use a new command `\inline{...}` instead of `$...$`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\inline}[1]{%
\nolinebreak$#1$%
}

\begin{document}
iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada
iada iada iada iada iada iada \inline{2+2=4} iada iada iada

iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada
iada iada iada iada iada \inline{2+2=4} iada iada iada
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

I don't think that redefining `$...$` is a good practice.

Anyway, you can do that by adding the following lines to your preamble (DISCLAIMER: I don't know if this can cause any other problem... Surely you don't have to use `$$...$$` but `\[...\]` instead):

```
\makeatletter
\let\inline=$
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\def$#1${%
  \nolinebreak\inline#1\inline%
}
\makeatother
```

so that the MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
\let\inline=$
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\def$#1${%
  \nolinebreak\inline#1\inline%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada
iada iada iada iada iada iada $2+2=4$ iada iada iada

iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada iada
iada iada iada iada iada $2+2=4$ iada iada iada
\end{document}
```

produces the same result as the above image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think it is possible to redefine the standard `$...$` to do just that? I would like to avoid changing to `inline{...}`in already existing documents.

Comment: @andrecb I won't do that... but see the edited answer.

Comment: @andrecb Does my answer is what you were looking for? If yes, please consider accepting the answer (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)).

Comment: sorry karlkoeller, I am just too much of a noob on this thing. your answer was just what I needed! thanks!